# Powershell directory and contents deletion

Tags: powershell

I wrote a powershell script to delete directories and their contents that are 6 months old or older:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-175)
Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\Wood\Jobs_to_Shop" -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $refDate } | Remove-Item -Force
```

My script is deleting the contents, however it appears to be either

- A) leaving the directories behind (including sub directories) and modifying the modified date.
- Or B) It is actually deleting the directories and then recreating them afterwards.

A friend recommended cutting the script into 3 parts:

1. Create list of directories to be deleted
2. Delete the files
3. Then delete the directories.

However I'm not the best with powershell scripting.

Comment: Yeah, it's deleting the content of the directories because `-File` is being specified. The switch will just return the files leaving the directories out of the query. You want `-Directory` instead if you're looking to compare directory creation time, and not file creation time. You can also just use `(Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)` instead.

Comment: So if a directory has files older than 6 month and also files that are newer what should happen?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - Thank you! I made those corrections, will test shortly before adding the script to group policy.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - If they're newer than 6 months, they need to stay put until 6month time period for their existence is up.

Comment: Made the correction and added in -Recurse to the other side of the pipe as well as -Confirm:$false as it was coming up asking for confirmation and still was not going back and getting the sub directories. This is now working the way it should! Thank you for all the help!